# Set default axis label interpreter Matlab R2015a

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

For me, it seems like the default interpreter for the axes labels are set to `'none'`, which in my case is undesirable, since I almost always need math symbols. Is there a way to change this? I've had no problem changing *TickInterpreter* or *TextInterpreter* by setting for example `set(groot, 'defaultAxesTickInterpreter', 'tex')`.

The problem seems to be that for the axes labels, according to the documentation page for axes properties:
`"Note:   To access the axis label text objects, use the XLabel, YLabel, and ZLabel properties or the xlabel, ylabel, and zlabel functions. These text objects are not contained in the axes Children property, they cannot be returned by findobj, and they do not use default values defined for text objects."`

This makes one unable to access the labels from groot and therefore one cannot set a default value from there. Is there any workaround? I don't want to set it manually every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create a function which includes this command for plotting, e.g.

```
function [~] = MyPlot()
    figure;
    set(gca,'name','value');
end
```

and then use `MyPlot` to open a figure as opposed to using `figure`. This is not a true default set, but easier than copying the line for `set()` on each plot.
`matlabroot` gives you the root folder of MATLAB, if you save `MyPlot` in there you will always have access to it without copying it to your present working directory (`pwd`).

Comment: Might I suggest an addition to this answer where you store the function somewhere in your Matlab path so you don't have to copy it to multiple places. It may not be entirely obvious to some people.

Comment: I actually copy my function to all paths, like a true moonlighter. Add an edit in the answer how to store it in the root folder or so and I'll approve that.

Comment: Yeah, I guess your solution might be the best solution if it's not possible to directly access and set the default value. Thanks!

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark on the left. This closes the question and gives me some reputation for helping you.

Comment: Of course, but I'm waiting until the end of the week, just to see if someone else have something to add.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd like to see a way to properly set defaults myself.